# My Lenovo IdeaPad screen went dim by accident

Tags: windows-7, lenovo-laptop

I accidentally pressed the wrong key (not sure which) while typing and my laptop's screen went dim. I can't get it to go back to how it was. (I'm using Windows 7 64 bit.)
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pressed key was <kbd>F11</kbd> (without the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key pressed). The IdeaPad uses this key for "decrease brightness". <kbd>F12</kbd> *should* do the opposite, but doesn't always work. To get it working, you need to edit the registry:

1. Open/run `regedit` <sup>1</sup>
2. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0000` <sup>2</sup>
3. Set the value of `"FeatureTestControl` to `0000f048` (hexadecimal)
4. Reboot
5. When Windows starts (or at any point while running), use the <kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> keys to adjust the brightness of your screen.

---

1. You might need to reinstall drivers for your graphics cards before this step.
2. You might need to navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0001` instead of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0000`

Source: [IdeaPad P500 screen went dim](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-P-Y-and-Z-series/IdeaPad-P500-screen-went-dim/m-p/1252053#M81589)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on Windows 10

> Open Device Manager (Search for it or right-click Start). Confirm the
>   UAC prompt, if necessary.
>
> Select Display Adapters and right-click on Intel HD Graphics 4000,
>   then select Update Driver > Browse my computer for driver software >
>   Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer. Choose
>   "Display Adapters" as Device Type and select Microsoft Basic Display
>   Adapter.

source: http://www.tenforums.com/general-discussion/10313-updated-windows-10-screen-now-very-dim-i-cant-adjust.html

Comment: It's not apparent how that solves the problem.