# I cannot adjust screen brightness in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have **Lenovo Ideapad Z510** with **Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600** and **NVIDIA GeForce 840M** and I cannot adjust the screen brightness, I think now it is 100%.

Yesterday there was no problems and it wasn't 100% bright. Might be due to an update. Normally I was adjusting the brightness with F11 and F12, they don't work now. Other keys suchs as F7 and F9 work without problem. When I search for "adjust screen brightness" I can see that there is a menu for that but when I click it shows me search results page with all settings, and there is no "adjust screen brightness".

Also I have tried to adjust screen brightness from power options but "screen brightness" doesn't exit there anymore. And I have reinstalled Intel drivers for graphics, it didn't help. What else I can do?

Answer (score 35):

1. Search for Device Manager in Start Menu
2. Expand the Monitors section
3. Right click on Generic PnP Monitor and
4. Click on Enable and you are good!

[Source](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/id-2742627/change-brightness-windows.html)

Comment: This fixed the same problem in Lenovo G50-80.

Comment: Wow, this fixed it for me on a totally different computer.

Comment: @Joao : PnP monitor is already enabled. I use lenovo idea pad z400. But still my screen brighness does not change

Comment: The Generic PnP monitor is not listed. Instead Generic Non PnP monitor option is displayed and its already enabled. Disabling it also doesn't help. Lenovo G500

Comment: Helped me with `HP Pavilion G6`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Since I can't add an answer, I'm linking to my answer in another question http://superuser.com/a/1020926/63504

Comment: +1 as it worked and fixed on Lenovo X220, it is interesting for I can't bring up this post searching `cannot adjust brightness windows 10`, but I found it by adding lenovo at the end `cannot adjust brightness windows 10 lenovo`, this should be the accepted answer

Comment: FYI I chose `update driver software` in step 4, on my T450.

Comment: Worked for me by uninstalling TeamViewer (it installs its own monitor driver). On a Lenovo G580

Comment: What the hell?  I can't believe this was the issue.  Thanks for the tip.  This is borderline easter egg and a terrible user experience!

Comment: strange it work for me when I disable monitor driver

Comment: Device Manager > Monitors > Right click on PnP Monitor > Update Drivers... > Browse My computer for driver software > Let me pick... > Select Generic PnP Monitor > Next. Now you can adjust brightness of the monitor

Answer (score 12):

This problem might appear with any graphics card on any laptop brand if you have installed the TeamViewer monitor driver to speed up change tracking on the screen.

To uninstall it, right click the Windows `Start` icon, choose `Device Manager`, expand `Monitors`, double click the `Generic PnP Monitor` and press `Uninstall` on the `Driver` tab. Now you have brightness controls again :)

There is an `Uninstall` button in TeamViewer next to the `Extras`->`Options`->`Advanced`->`Advanced Network Options`->`Install monitor driver` label if you have installed this driver, but that did not work for me.

Comment: If that still doesn't help, try this: https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3fa2ph/having_problems_adjusting_brightness/ctunq4b In short: change the Monitor device driver to "Generic PnP Monitor".

Comment: @vadipp: Thanks. TeamViewer failed to uninstall its driver on my computer. Forcing Windows to reinstall the Generic PnP driver as it said in that reddit post worked. In case the link goes down: Device Manager -> Monitors -> Right-click on Generic PnP -> Update -> From my computer -> Let me choose from a list -> Generic PnP -> Update.

Comment: @wigy Man you are great! Thanks. That did the trick. Uninstalling monitor driver in team viewer didn't work for me either. I had to uninstall PnP Monitor.

Answer (score 2):

In my Lenovo G500 laptop after installing Windows 10 I couldn't adjust the screen brightness. And I couldn't see the Generic PnP Monitor option under the Monitor section of my device manager list. I had installed the **Intel HD 4000 Graphics** and **AMD Radeon Graphics** drivers.  Enabling and disabling it doesn't help either.

But the thing is I haven't installed the **Intel Chipset Driver** software. After installing the motherboard driver software I was able to adjust the screen brightness after a system restart. And now under Display settings Windows has the Screen brightness slider added. Also the shortcut to increase and decrease using F11 and F12 also works. You can also click the battery icon near the tray and change the battery percentages to 0%, 25%, 75% & 100%. These options were not enabled before installing the motherboard(Chipset) drivers.

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, most laptops (especially newer ones) allow you to change the main monitor's brightness in the BIOS. Of course this isn't ideal, but if nothing else works, it's better than nothing.