# Dim screen on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop

So, I've had the update for about a week and honestly I've been loving it so far. Only problem was I couldn't regulate screen brightness which was stuck at 100%. But I chose to ignore this, until today when it dropped down to minimum. I almost can't read the screen unless I move to a dark room like I did to type this post =/

Adaptive screen brightness is disabled.

I'm using a Lenovo IdeaPad Z400. I tried to update drivers but Lenovo hasn't released any updates for Windows 10. Can anybody please help? I can barely use my computer like this, it's very frustrating :(

EDIT: I tried this solution offered on a similar post and it didn't work:

```
Search for Device Manager in Start Menu
Expand the Monitors section
Right click on Generic PnP Monitor and
Click on Enable and you are good!
```

The Generic PnP Monitor was already on so this wasn't the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I cannot adjust screen brightness in Windows 10](http://superuser.com/questions/948587/i-cannot-adjust-screen-brightness-in-windows-10)

Comment: @Moab Not a duplicate, my problem is not solved by the answer provided on theother thread.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please post your solution as an answer (yes, you may answer your own question here) rather editing it into your question. Thank you.

Comment: The question is duplicate, but maybe not the answer.

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I finally know the answer - and it's not pleasant. 
This solution on Reddit partially solved my problem:

> So I managed to fix the Brightness problem on my Lenovo Z500
>   (non-touch) here's what I did
>
> 1  Downloaded the Intel Video Drivers for 8.1 off the Lenovo Website
>
> 2   Ran the unpacker but >did not install< once unpacked
>
> 3   Navigated to C:\Drivers\Intel Video Driver\9.17.10.3223
>
> (On mine there are two folders like this http://prntscr.com/7z1wrq[1] 
>   )
>
> 4 Inside 9.17.xxx right click setup -> run as administrator
>
> 5 Run installer
>
> Once it finished I was able to change brightness again

Problem is, the driver doesn't work perfectly, so it would raise brightness to the maximum and it'd be stuck there. If I tried to lower it, it would drop to min and I'd have to reinstall the driver again. I chose to use the screen on max brightness for a while, until I got tired of this and other compatibility problems and decided to go back to 8.1

Answer (score -2):

Pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> will give you a little brightness changer in the top left. You can click on that and adjust your brightness.

Comment: That's Volume no brightness !!

Comment: The button changes based on the computer, not all computers will use `F3` or even have a button binded to change brightness (e.g. my Surface Pro 3).