# Samsung laptop won't adjust screen brightness

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, brightness

I have a Samsung Ativ Book 6 NP680Z5E-X02US and recently updated to Windows 10. It uses Intel HD 4000 Graphics and has and AMD Radeon 8770M graphics card. Since updating I am no longer able to adjust screen brightness.

I have tried uninstalling the monitor and restarting. Updating all the graphics drivers. Disabling/Enabling the generic PnP monitor in device manager. Changed all of the power settings. The monitor still stays at what seems to be 100% brightness.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: there is a driver of piece of software  that you need to download from samsung for that..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I cannot adjust screen brightness in Windows 10](http://superuser.com/questions/948587/i-cannot-adjust-screen-brightness-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 4):

My system is a ATIV Book 8, model NP880Z5E-X01UB. Also Intel HD 4000 and Radeon 8700M GPUs.

I recently updated W10 to anniversary edition and ran into this issue yet again. I have no idea how I was able to resolve it last time. I attempted to uninstall, and reinstall all drivers from Samsung over again, in various orders, running the Win10 Brightness Control Patch each time provided by Samsung Update, but in each case, never yielded results. I should also note that I've also disabled adaptive brightness in display options and also my power options plan. This was required the first time I got this working so I made sure those settings were changed back after the update reverted them.

After some more intense googling.. I finally found a solution that worked for me.

Modify the following registry key(s):

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0001]

**FeatureTestControl**

Change **f000** to **f008**

There are other "control sets" other than the *CurrentControlSet*. I wound up changing them all to **f008** prior to a reboot. Though I suspect the **CurrentControlSet** is all you will need.

Source: https://communities.intel.com/thread/81571

As always, careful when modifying the registry.

Comment: I just cannot believe it that this fixed my display brightness issue which I had since 2018 on my Samsung 730U (NP730U3E). This seems to reactivate DDC communication to the display from the driver and thus allows tools such as TwinkleTray.com to work. This didn't fix the function keys for me, but after installing the Samsung Easy Display Manager also that worked again.

Answer (score 2):

It was fixed for me by windows update, probably this component: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. - Display - 27.20.1034.6

Answer (score 1):

The monitor and video card have their own brightness settings, independent of one another.

I know this may sound obvious, but have you tried:

- <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>brightness buttons</kbd> for *monitor brightness*?
- <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to change *video card* brightness it via the Mobility Centre?
- AMD Catylist Control Center (if available for your video card since it's AMD)?

Comment: i've seen a samsung laptop, and on that and probably his too,  there's some driver that enables the function keys

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar model NP680Z5E-X03US. Brightness control is completely unavailable using any version of either the Intel or Radeon display drivers. Neither keyboard control, system settings, display control, nor any other kind of brightness control will work.

One solution is to go into Computer Management → Display and install the "Microsoft Basic Display Adapter" as the display driver.  Brightness control will work, but then all dual display functionality is lost. My choice is either brightness control or dual display, but not both.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Samsung Ativ Book 9 and have been experiencing the same issue since the Windows 10 Creators Update. I've managed to at least find somewhat of a work-around (not a permanent fix):

1. Go to Device Manager > Display Adapter > Update driver
2. Select from list > Select "Microsoft Basic Display Adapter" and install
3. Reboot your laptop. The Fn+brightness keys should now work again.
4. You can now update again to the latest drivers, the brightness keys will remain functioning. However, if you reboot again, they will stop working again.

I'm still looking for a permanent fix.

Answer (score 1):

For me the display was disabled in device manger after driver update. 
I enabled it, then the brightness keys worked again.

Comment: It would be better is you added some details to this, like the exact sequence of steps.  A screenshot might be nice. (Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.)

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue. You need to install Samsung Settings VERSION 3.1
To find this you will have to use samsung update and search in other models drivers and programs list. 
Mine Ativ 6 is XD1BR and I used the Samsung Settings softwre found in XF3BR list.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [alt] + [fn] + [f4] which I found in Easy Display Manager's Option window. I didn't know what would happen but the screen cycled through various appearances and suddenly the [fn] + brightness buttons worked like a charm!

Hope this works for you, too!

[image: Easy display manager option appearance under windows 7]

Answer (score 1):

Best way to download and install the below utility from Samsung.

I have downloaded it works perfectly for me.

http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/SW/201101/20110114153004115/Easy_Display_Manager_3.2.5.5.ZIP